# How to set $watch on change in element's position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to Angular and programming world. I have a directive for d3 graph in a div and also a collapsible side menu directive.
I need to call resize() function of graph controller when the side menu is collapsed. I want the graph to expand and shrink depending on whether the side menu is collapsed or open.

When the side menu is collapsed, the graph shifts to the left by 235px, I have tried to setup a watch on the x coordinate (left position) of the graph directive element and call resize() function;
 I have the following code so far:

```
  $scope.$watch(function() {
            return $element[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
        }, function() {
            if (graph) {
                graph.resize();
            }
        });
```

Problem: The resize function is called and works as expected only when I hover over the mouse on graph after side menu collapsed or opened. I want to call the resize function without hovering over the mouse on the graph area. Seems like watch is getting executed only on mouseover. Something unexpected behavior is happening. I spent hours to implement this feature without success.

Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong please?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the resize happens outside AngularJS? If so it might be that the $digest process doesn't run when you collapse the side menu but angular is responding to mouse event (dunno why, i don't know your app structure) and then it works

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Yes, resize function is a separate javascript object where the function is defined. and in the controller,  i initialise the graph object like: graph=new chart($scope, $element, $ettr).

Comment: var chart = function($scope, $element, $attrs) {} inside this object, i have resize function: this.resize=function(){setup canvas()}

Comment: $scope.$watch($attrs.graphData, function(graphData) {
            if (graphData) {
                if (!graph) {
                    graph = new chart($scope, $element, $attrs)
                }
                graph.updateData(graphData, minShownDate, maxShownDate);
            }

Comment: I'll need yo to extend your code and create fiddle so I can answer properly

Comment: It's a large scale app, I will have trouble simulating this issue in fiddle. I will try though.

Comment: I have $window.onresize as well which works fine when i resize the window. But having trouble setting $watch on div's position change. There should be a way to set watch when the position of the directive changes. Haven't seen any example doing this. There is some changes in the dom when side menu collapsed or expand, because I can see graph shifting back and forth. I was expecting The Angular to recognize the change event via $watch.

Comment: If you have $window.onresize and it's working everytime, you can call a function from that level

Comment: $scope.$watch(function() {
            return angular.element($window)[0].innerWidth;
        }, function() {
            if (graph) {
                graph.resize();
            }
        }); this is how i have implemented window resize, not sure what does it mean by calling a function from that level. Side menu have different controller and directive than graph. I have no access to side menu collapse click event in graph directive or controller and therefore trying to make it work through graph's controller.

Answer (score 0):

$scope.$watch watches only $scope's properties.
You can add flag to your $scope and change it's state when menu changes it's visibility. It's up to you how you would reach that (`<a class="menu-toggler" ng-click="menuVisible=!menuVisible">toggle menu</a>` for example). Then:

```
$scope.menuVisible = true; // or false
$scope.$watch('menuVisible', function() {
     if (graph) {
           graph.resize();
     }
});
```

**Upd**
I beg my pardon: it seems like it *does* watch functions.

$watch triggers on $digest cycle. See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) :

```
scope.$watch(
     function() { return food; },
     function(){}
);
food = 'cheeseburger';
scope.$digest();
```

So it seems like when you hover graph - something in your $scope is changed and $digest is started.

To achieve your desired behavior, you anyway should trigger something within $scope. It may be $event, $digest, any $scope.property - something.

Comment: Yes, I needed to trigger $scope.$aaply() when sidemenu collapsed or expanded.